# Python: flatten function works in console but not in file?

Tags: python, flatten

I'm doing an exercise to flatten nested lists.  The code works in console but it doesn't work when its in a file.  I have no idea what's going on.  :(

```
def flatten(nested):
    """
            >>> flatten([2, 9, [2, 1, 13, 2], 8, [2, 6]])
            [2, 9, 2, 1, 13, 2, 8, 2, 6]
            >>> flatten([[9, [7, 1, 13, 2], 8], [7, 6]])
            [9, 7, 1, 13, 2, 8, 7, 6]
            >>> flatten([[9, [7, 1, 13, 2], 8], [2, 6]])
            [9, 7, 1, 13, 2, 8, 2, 6]
            >>> flatten([[5, [5, [1, 5], 5], 5], [5, 6]])
            [5, 5, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6]
    """
    simple = []

    for x in nested:
            if type(x) == type([]):
                    for y in x:
                            simple.append(y)
            else:
                    simple.append(x)
    return simple



if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

I first tried to solve this exercise recursively but decided to try it iterative first.

edit: When executed in the file it just prints out the original function argument
TIA

Comment: Are you getting a specific error, what do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: Your indentation doesn't make sense as posted.  Please check carefully that the body of the function is actually indented.

Comment: Are you missing some indentation for the function body?

Comment: Sorry about that.  I edited my post with what the function returned.  It just returns a list thats exactly the same as the arg.

Comment: It's indented, i can never get SO's code formatting to work for me.

Comment: How are you calling the function in 'the file'?

Comment: Minor nitpick: just use the type name instead of calling `type` on an instance of it... `type(x) == list`, `not type(x) == type([])`

Comment: My first glance says your iterative solution is broken.  I suggest you test any function you write with this `[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[1]]]]]]]]]]]]]]],2]` (output: `[1,2]`)

Comment: @orangeoctopus - via doctests

Comment: @centr0, your code mixed tabs and spaces (a bad idea when writing Python, and apparently not good when writing SO questions) - I replaced the tabs with 8 space. Is this what your code looks like?

Comment: @blair thanks for correcting it.  yes thats exactly what my code looks like.

Comment: @Nick T: A slightly less minor nitpick: as I remember it, the preferred method is to use `isinstance(obj, class_or_type)` rather than `type(x) == typename`, as `isinstance` will also return `True` if the object is an instance of a subclass of the given class/type, which is usually desired behavior. Also it seems to be slightly more powerful based on the fact that you can use tuples of classes/types instead of a single one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your flatten function only flattens one level. The reason why doctest is printing out errors is because it is indeed erroring. They are not what you passed in.

```
File "test.py", line 5, in __main__.flatten
Failed example:
    flatten([[9, [7, 1, 13, 2], 8], [7, 6]])
Expected:
    [9, 7, 1, 13, 2, 8, 7, 6]
Got:
    [9, [7, 1, 13, 2], 8, 7, 6]
```

You should investigate a recursive approach that instead of appending  `y`--- you call flatten on `y` as well. `if type(x) != type([])` can be your base case.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to "cheat" you could do this:

```
L = [1, 2, [3, 4], 5, 6, [7, 8, [9, 10, 11]]]
s = repr(L)
s = '[' + s.replace('[','').replace(']','') + ']'
L = eval(s)
```

I'm kind of curious how fast that would be compared to the "normal" flattening operation...

---

### Edit:

A cursory test shows that the cheating method takes nearly constant time regardless of data complexity, while a recursive solution increases in time.

Larger

> Cheat:  7.13282388182 
> Recurse: 2.84676811407

Smaller

> Cheat:  7.08800692623 
> Recurse:  0.486098086038

Here's my code (and I'm really curious about larger data sets!):

```
import timeit

L = [1,2,3,
     [46, 100000, 20, 9, 
      [1,2,3, 
       [9, 23, 24, 
        [9, 23, 24, 
         [9, 23, 24, 
          [9, 23, 24, 
           [9, 23, 24, [9, 23, 24, [13], 12],4]]]], 26]]]]

L2 = [1,2,3, [4,5,6]]

def flattencheat(mylist):
    s = repr(L)
    s = '[' + s.replace('[', '').replace(']', '') + ']'
    return eval(s)

def flattencurse(mylist):
    newlist = []
    for val in mylist:
        if not hasattr(val, '__iter__'):
            newlist.append(val)
        else:
            newlist.extend(flattencurse(val))

    return newlist

print "Cheat: ", timeit.timeit('flattencheat(L)', "from __main__ import flattencheat, L", number=100000)
print "Recurse: ", timeit.timeit('flattencurse(L)', 
                                 'from __main__ import flattencurse, L',
                                 number = 100000)
print "Cheat: ", timeit.timeit('flattencheat(L2)', "from __main__ import flattencheat, L2", number=100000)
print "Recurse: ", timeit.timeit('flattencurse(L2)', 
                                 'from __main__ import flattencurse, L2',
                                 number = 100000)
```

Comment: Hmm... what happens if one of the elements is dictionary or object?

Comment: In the recursive test it will flatten the keys only. As for object, it depends on how and if it implements __repr__ and __iter__. Not a robust solution by any means, but the OP's specific request was dealing with nested lists.

Answer (score 0):

Your application is not doing nothing.

```
Input:  [3,[5, [5, [1, 5], 5], 5], [5, 6]]
Output: [3, 5, [5, [1, 5], 5], 5 ,  5, 6]
```

You need to keep flattening until it completes, e.g. using recursion.  Simple but with one extra pass over your data: If `type(x) == type([])`, return `flatten(simple)` instead of `simple` at the end of the function.

Answer (score 0):

I think that @orangeoctopus's answer is correct, but doesn't capture the "why does it work in the console" question. I'm going to make a guess:

*It doesn't work in the console.* I think you tested with a subset of the input that happens to work. For example,

```
>>> flatten([2, 9, [2, 1, 13, 2], 8, [2, 6]])
[2, 9, 2, 1, 13, 2, 8, 2, 6]
```

works!

But

```
>>> flatten([[9, [7, 1, 13, 2], 8], [7, 6]])
[9, [7, 1, 13, 2], 8, 7, 6]
```

does not so much.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is pretty similiar to @DonaldMiner's (In fact I started out with that as well), but then noticed that if a string in the list contains `"["` or `"]"`, it would fail.

E.g. won't work here:

```
["Hello", "World", "A", "[Menu]"]
```

I wrote a similiar function (a little more complex, and only removes the `[` and `]` if it is not in a string in the list.

```
from ast import literal_eval
def flatten(to_squash):
    """This will flatten a list, no matter the recursion limit."""
    instring = False
    squashed = []
    index = 0
    print(repr(to_squash))
    for char in repr(to_squash):
        if char == '"' or char == "'":
            instring = not instring
            print(instring, char)
            squashed.append(char)
        elif not instring and char == "[" or not instring and char == "]":
            pass
        else:
            squashed.append(char)
        index += 1

    print("".join([item.strip() for item in squashed]))
    return literal_eval("".join(squashed))
```

You could of course also use `eval()`, but only if you dont read in the list from somwhere (It is made by the program). Otherwise, someone can just enter a command, and python will execute it.